# How to remove cart icon from primary menu navigation bar in woo commerce wordpress site

Tags: woocommerce

I wanted to remove the cart icon from my nav bar using woocommerce. There did not seem to be a setting in the admin to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code

```
function remove_nav_cart_link () {
    remove_action( 'woo_nav_inside', 'woo_add_nav_cart_link', 20);
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_nav_cart_link' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The setting is under WooThemes -> WooCommerce -> Header Cart Link

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for me the following solution worked but nothing else

Just added the following code in Theme's custom css

Appearance>Themes>Your theme>Custom CSS

```
#top .wc-nav li.cart {
display: none !important;}
#top .wc-nav li.checkout{
display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/inc/woocommerce/yourthemename-woocommerce-template-hook

search for

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_product_search', 40 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart',    60 );
```

comment these 2 lines..!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use WooTheme, just the WooCommerce plugin and the header cart still appeared in my premium theme, so instead of disabling it by a function I just used the following CSS code in my child theme..

```
#Top_bar a#header_cart { display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `\wamp64\www\....\wp-content\themes\yourtheme\includes\header-top-bar-right`

Find line WooCommerce Cart

Comment the line out:

```
echo '<a id="header_cart" href="'. $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() .'"><i class="'. $show_cart .'"></i><span>'. $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count .'</span></a>';
```